# ExtJs page makes no response while using the second time - on IE9 only

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs

When I my **ExtJS** page opened in **IE9** for the first time, works properly.

But when I open the same page for a second time I don't get a response. 
Can someone help me.

*PS I am only getting this error on IE9*

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try? Please add some more details

Comment: It is about expanding a folder on clicking, for the first time I'm able to do it without any problem, then I closed the window. When I open the window for the second time and try to expand the folder, there is no response from the UI, there is no call made to the dwr. (only in IE9)

Comment: rewrite to make clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds that you have problems with your Ids and the Ext.cache. Please check your panels, windows and so on. Dont use the property [id](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-id) use [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-itemId) instead.

If you use an id in your datasource check that the ids are unique. Otherwise you become some problems during rendering of gridpanel, treestore, combobox and so on...